# Custom push notification sound( .wav ) file is not playing in ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, push

> aps ={ alert = "push message"; badge = 1; id = 557; sound =
>   "seller.wav"; type = 107; };

Though i have added "seller.wav" file in my bundle I could not able to play custom sound,when push comes.

Help me to get this solve.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for me custom sound does not plays i tried ur way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check 'Preparing custom alert sounds' in the documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html

You file might not be the right format. Apple recommends the CAF file format. You can convert a wav file to CAF using afconvert like this:

afconvert /System/Library/Sounds/Submarine.aiff ~/Desktop/sub.caf -d ima4 -f caff -v

(Also from Apple doc)

Comment: i've also tried CAF file but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Finally i resolved this problem by using "wav" file and I had to delete an application from device and now working fine.